# Shortest code for a codegolf-style character counter without using bash

Tags: code-golf

You have to write a program that will count all the characters in specified source file so that people entering a code golf competition can see their score. You do not need to ignore comments (it is code golf) in your program but newlines should be counted as a character. The number of characters must be printed to stdout. Shortest code wins!

Example in python:

```
import sys

try:
    content = open(sys.argv[1], "r").read()
except IndexError, e:
    print("No file specified")
    sys.exit(1)
except IOError, e:
    print("File not found")
    sys.exit(1)

count = 0
for i in list(content):
    if(i!=''):
        count+=1

print(str(count)+" characters long")
```

Note: you cannot use the bash command `wc -c`.

Comment: 5 chars in bash. `wc -c`. This is trivial.

Comment: "Note: you cannot use the bash command `wc -c`." You can't fix a broken problem by banning one example of why it's so broken.

Comment: Question seems trivial. Also banning 'bash' while not banning the other '*sh' languages is essentially pointless.

Comment: In the future, you might want to run your questions by the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xi) to get help ironing out any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Dash, 18

```
tr \\0-ÿ \\n|wc -l
```

Reads from STDIN. Doesn't use `wc -c` or Bash.

Answer (score 4):

## bash+coreutils, 7 chars

```
stat $1
```